# regex_replace to replace certain html tags

Tags: perl, content-management-system, movabletype

Is there a way to convert BR tags and/or DIV tags to new lines so it will format correctly when I use an  in a mailto? I was thinking I should look for any P, DIV, and BR tags and replace them with a new line character. So anywhere there is a closing tag put the new line character and remove the opening tag. After I do the above I will remove the rest of the html with remove_html="1" but I want to keep the paragraph format.

I thought it can be done using regex_replace but I'm not sure how to write it. Anyone know?

Comment: Relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: i would use xslt for those transformations...

Comment: Step away from the regex..... Or: put down the regex and nobody gets hurt...

Answer (score 0):

Do not parse HTML files using regex, use HTML parser (HTML::TreeBuilder or something similar that  can do in line changes) module, or in this case, even better use XSLT transformations.